# Appending to XML in ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I'm trying to append to an XML in ASP Classic and the code I've found online doesn't seem to do the trick for me. Here is the code I'm using to test:

```
Set objxml2 = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
objxml2.async = False
objxml2.load (server.mappath("organizations.xml"))

Set node = objxml2.createElement("organization")
objxml2.documentElement.AppendChild node

Set typeEl = objxml2.createElement("type")
typeEl.Text = "TheType"
node.AppendChild typeEl

Set objxml2 = Nothing
node = Nothing
Set typeEl = Nothing
```

The XML file organizations.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
</Data>
```

And when I run the code I don't get any errors on the browser but the code doesn't show up in the file. The reason I'm appending rather than creating a new file is because this will be an ongoing list that will always be updating. Am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the Document after appending and before setting objects to nothing :

`objxml2.save(server.mappath("organizations.xml"))`